# Tensorflow data import

Tags: tensorflow

I just started to use tensorflow, but I failed to import the data properly to use with the DNNClassifier. I actually have two files in the hdf5 format, that I import with pandas. The feature vector has dimension 100 and there are 5 classes where the features can belong to. If I use for example the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

#Data
train = pd.read_hdf("train.h5", "train")
test = pd.read_hdf("test.h5", "test")

Y=train.iloc[0:,0]
X=train.iloc[0:,1:]
X_t=test.iloc[0:,0:]

Y=np.array(Y.values).astype('int')
X=np.array(X.values).astype('double')
X_t=np.array(X_t.values).astype('double')

#Train
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=100)]
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                          hidden_units=[10, 20],
                                          n_classes=5,
                                          model_dir="/tmp/model")
# Define the training inputs
def get_train_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(X)
    y = tf.constant(Y)
    return x, y

#fit
classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=1000)
predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=get_train_inputs))
print(predictions)
```

I get the error: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape in shape_and_slice spec [100,10] does not match the shape stored in checkpoint: [1,10]
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_2/shape_and_slices)]]

I don't get why this happens? How should I transform my data to apply to this classifier?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:-

Change your model_dir="/tmp/model" to

```
 model_dir="/tmp/model-1
```

Note:- It need not to be model-1, replace it with any valid names like

model_dir="/tmp/model-a ..something like that..